# How can I get an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by an SQS message to fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a Java AWS Lambda function that is triggered from an SQS queue. All of documentation suggests that if the Lambda function fails, the message will not be deleted from the queue and will be available to be reprocesses once the visibility timeout expires. This is the behavior I want, but this is not what I am seeing.

In fact, I am not seeing the Lambda function fail **at all** when an exception is thrown from the Java code. I do see that the exception is logged in CloudWatch. For example, when the payload is not well formed JSON, I see this in the CloudWatch logs:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'This': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: (String)"This make no sense!!!!!!!"; line: 1, column: 5]
...
```

Clearly the exception is bubbling up and being processed. However, the CloudWatch metrics indicate the invocation succeeded. I am clearly missing something. Is there something else that needs to be configured in order to treat unhandled exceptions as Lambda error conditions?

Comment: What is your message visibility timeout? I'm assuming you waited that long (default is 30 seconds). Does CloudWatch Logs for your Lambda show that it failed in error?

Comment: Lambda timeout is 30 seconds. Visibility timeout for queue is 5 minutes (recommended 6x of Lambda timeout). I am not sure how to see if failed in CloudWatch Logs. I don't see anything that indicates success or failure for any of the Lambda invocations in the logs. However, the CloudWatch metrics, all I see are successful invocations, no errors.

Comment: If you catch the exception in you lambda code and return from lambda normally, then the lambda returns normally. You have to re-throw the exception in lambda, so that event source mapping which is feeding SQS messages into your function retry.

Comment: @Marcin The exception that is being thrown is a RuntimeException that the Lambda function is not catch. It is bubbling up all the way to the entrypoint unhandled.

Comment: Disregard. Bad assumption on my part. I thought the exception being thrown _was_ a `RuntimeException`. It is actually a subclass of `IOException`, which the code is catching, so the function exits successfully. It is working as designed.